# What is the difference between React-Native-Windows and Electron?

Tags: electron, react-native-windows

I'm using React Native to build Mobile Application but I get a request to build on both windows and suggested use react-native-windows. I'm very confused because react-native-windows too low questions on StackOverflow and I know Electron is very popular for build desktop applications. How do I should use for build Desktop application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`Electron.js`** use chrome engine for rendering UI. and use actual html elements for UI.

**`React-native-windows`** use native windows UI. so it's more performant and more light than electron.js

Both of them are Javascript Frameworks.

Comment: I saw react-native windows also able to develop mac application. My question is react native windows also make native mac applications?

Comment: for macos there is another repository by Microsoft by the name of react-native-macos

Answer (score 3):

react-native-windows is Microsoft's framework for building native Windows apps.

Electron is a framework for building cross-platform desktop apps (Chromium WebView + Node.js).